# How to get Current location with Zoom Extent

Tags: android, arcgis

I am getting current location in my application  with using LocationListener.But problem is when i apply zoom to map,first time the zoom shows current location but after some time the zoom goes to sea.I am unable to find solution for this from last 3 day,please tell me any one

My Activity

```
   loc = mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager();
    loc.setAutoPanMode(AutoPanMode.LOCATION);
    loc.setLocationListener(new MyLocationListener(LaunchingMapActivity.this,mMapView)); 
     loc.start();
            mLocation = loc.getPoint();
            Log.e("mLocation", ""+mLocation);
            mapLocatiomFromLoc = loc.getLocation();

            double longitude=mapLocatiomFromLoc.getLongitude();
            double latitude=mapLocatiomFromLoc.getLatitude();
            p=new Point((float)longitude,(float)latitude);
```

MyLocationListener:

```
 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
Geometry mLocation = null;
private MapView mMapView;
private Context mContext;


public MyLocationListener(Context context,MapView mapView) {
    super();
    this.mMapView=mapView;
}

/**
 * If location changes, update our current location. If being found for
 * the first time, zoom to our current position with a resolution of 20
 */
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc1) {
    if (loc1 == null)
        return;
    boolean zoomToMe = (mLocation == null) ? true : false;
    mLocation = new Point(loc1.getLongitude(), loc1.getLatitude());
    Log.e("ONCHANGEmLocation", ""+mLocation);
    if (zoomToMe) {

         Point mPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(mLocation, SpatialReference.create(20439)
                    ,SpatialReference.create(20439));
        Log.e("mPoint",""+ mPoint);
        // graphic = new Graphic((Geometry) p, (Symbol) sms, hm);
        // locationLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
       // mMapView.zoomToResolution(mPoint, 20.0);
    }
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "GPS Disabled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "GPS Enabled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
```

}

Comment: the map usually zoom in on the center, so if you are not on the center of the map then successive zoom will zoom you out. Just implement `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` to give you a button to pan to your current location.

Comment: thank you for reply but there is no method setMyLocationEnabled(true) on my map

Comment: you need to get a reference to `GoogleMap` by using `mapView.getMap()`. Then `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`.

Comment: it is not google map,here i am not able to find setMyLocationEnabled(true) on map

Comment: Yes, I know there is no method `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` on MapView. Its a method of GoogleMap. [Map Objects - Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)

Comment: i used this mMapView.centerAndZoom(lat, lon, 20); but no result

Comment: Sorry, I've just realized that you are using ArcGIS instead of GoogleMap. One question, Why use ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0):

you need to setCenter() with your current location

try the following code

```
     MapController mc;
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
   myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
   overlays.add(myLocOverlay);
   myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();*

   // definitely need what's below
   int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
   int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
   GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
   mc.setCenter(point);
   mapView.invalidate();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS you can show current user location like this:

```
LocationDisplayManager mLDM = mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager();

mLDM.setShowLocation(true);
```